# Prevent reorder first column

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview

I have a listview which contains a gridview with gridcolumns, i want to reorder all columns except first column. How can i do this? Also i want to save new columns position.

My code for the listview is:

```
<Style x:Key="myListViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}"  x:Shared="False">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="RoyalBlue" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="Teal" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20, 60, 20, 50" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4, 4, 4, 4" />
        <Setter Property="ListView.View">
            <Setter.Value>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True" >
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="A/A" Width="30" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding AA}"></GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Price" Width="350" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}" >
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Shop" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Shop}" >
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Also i create the listview in code like that:

```
 ListView l1 = new ListView();
 l1.Style = Resources["myListViewStyle"] as Style;
```

Comment: Link here might be of your intereset - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/cb349eb9-f08d-4f62-8e99-40187ea122fc

Comment: Thanks, he use events ColumnReordered and ColumnReordering, but i can't found them, how can i use them?

Answer (score 1):

If it is only the first column you want to kepp in place, try this:

**XAML:**

```
<GridViewColumnHeader x:Name="FirstColumn" MouseMove="PreventDrag">
```

**Code behind:**

```
public MyWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    (MyListview.View as GridView).Columns.CollectionChanged += ColumnsReordered;
}

private void PreventDrag(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        e.Handled = true;
}

private void ColumnsReordered(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move)
    {
        var columns = sender as GridViewColumnCollection;
        if (columns != null)
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => columns.Move(columns.IndexOf(FirstColumn.Column), 0)));
    }
}
```